# ¿Cómo puedo implementar un proyecto ASP.NET Framework, usando SQL Server 2019 y Somee.com como hosting?

Tags: asp.net, mvc, framework

Tengo este proyecto corriendo localmente y a la hora de subirlo y hacer pruebas de por ejemplo crear un nuevo usuario, noto que se sigue conectando a la base de datos local y no a la que configuré que se usara para Somee.com. Sospecho que tiene que ver con mi connection string la cual es la siguiente:

```
<add name="BD_MARYSTYLISEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=BD_MARYSTYLIST2.mssql.somee.com;initial catalog=BD_MARYSTYLIST2;user id=user;pwd=password;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

¿Alguna sugerencia para hacer que el proyecto se conecte directamente a la base de datos de Somee.com?